# Set a value displayed in a dropdown

Tags: magento

I need some help please!!

In my store I have a dropdown box that displays the size options of the USB flash drives sold. For example ... I have a 4Gb USB Drive for $ 45, and in this menu the customer can choose a larger size for 8 Gb.
But the dropdown displays the size option and the price difference between one and the other ...
Something like this: (8GB + $ 10). This option is changed dynamically and represents the price difference between 4GB and 8GB Drives. I need to remove this value (+ $10) and leave only the sizes of USB drives for display.

This is the code that runs this block: The file is in (configurable.phtml).

public_html/techinfobh.com.br/app/design/frontend/default/weddingsilver/template/catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml

There are two js files: product.js and configurable.js located in (js/varien).

If someone can help me.... Sorry for terrible english and for the giant text..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can override configurable.js in your skin or magento js folder

Create one file named : `configurable.js` in add it to your js folder

write in your `local.xml` or any custom xml of your extension

```
<catalog_product_view>
     <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs"><script>yourjsfolder/configurable.js</script></action>            
        </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

And add below code to in this js like below

```
if (typeof Product.Config != 'undefined') {
    Product.Config.addMethods({
        getOptionLabel: function(option, price){
        var price = parseFloat(price);
        if (this.taxConfig.includeTax) {
            var tax = price / (100 + this.taxConfig.defaultTax) * this.taxConfig.defaultTax;
            var excl = price - tax;
            var incl = excl*(1+(this.taxConfig.currentTax/100));
        } else {
            var tax = price * (this.taxConfig.currentTax / 100);
            var excl = price;
            var incl = excl + tax;
        }

        if (this.taxConfig.showIncludeTax || this.taxConfig.showBothPrices) {
            price = incl;
        } else {
            price = excl;
        }

        var str = option.label;

        return str;
    }
    });
}
```

hope this will sure help you.

Comment: Thanks... You helped me a lot.
Worked perfectly.

Comment: @Gustavo, welcome. Will you please accept my answer ? so if someone has to do same thing in future so they can utilize our thread.